# OpenSSL.net: null Ciphers

Tags: c#

all,

I'm looking into OpenSSL.NET and have hit a bit of a wall with it. As I said, I'm only looking into it, but a project at work needs to use it, so I can't really use anything else. The problem I'm getting is that I'm using the Cipher attribute to select an encyption type, yet each one throws the following error:

```
The type initializer for 'OpenSSL.Crypto.Cipher' threw an exception.
```

Also, when I look at the debugger, each Cipher has "null" as it's value. I've got the ManagedOpenSsl.dll referenced, and libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll are both in the working directory, so I'm a tad stuck.

Any help on this would be much appreciated. Also, has anyone found any good stuff to read on the OpenSSL library? I've spent two hours looking, but nothing useful shows up.

Cheers

Comment: You need to post the `InnerException`.

Comment: It's possible you're running into the `cdecl` vs. `stdcall` import signature issue.

Comment: Anything SSL related in .net sucks. OpenSSL.NET has several severe bugs, .net's built in implementation doesn't allow you to enforce the use of secure cipher suites, Mono doesn't support secure cipher suites in the first place, BouncyCastle is client only, and GnuTLS has no bindings.

Comment: Thanks. Is there anything you can suggest then? The library needs to be used is all (I've tried to override the signature import, but to no avail).

Comment: What library you should use depends on your exact requirements. But if you want to figure out what the issue with OpenSSL.NET is, you need to find the InnerException.

Comment: Found the error using dtb's answer listed at the following [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876456/how-do-i-find-the-inner-most-exception-without-using-a-while-loop). Thanks for the advice, Chaos ;)

Comment: If you're using a debugger you can simply view it in the exception details dialog. No need to code anything.